# no debuggable process detected on android studio 4.0

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]
I use LG V50
Enable developer mode and USB debugging
Connected V50 to Mac and launch android studio 4.0
I try to layout inspector but could not select process
shows "no debuggable process detected"

Comment: Are you sure your app is running ? on device ?

Comment: Yes. I luanched app on android device